# biblatex-chicago (author-date) displays a redefined postnotedelim when only displaying the page number

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago, texlive-2021

When using `biblatex-chicago`, if you change the `\postnotedelim` with a command like

`\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}`

and compile on Overleaf using TeX Live 2021, things don't turn out too well. Compiling the same code on TeX Live 2020 or previous works great.

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[authordate]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Jones2016,
    author = {Jones, John},
    title = {Title},
    date = {2016},
}

@book{Smith2018,
    author = {Smith, Sam},
    title = {Title},
    date = {2018},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}

\begin{document}

\textcite[9]{Jones2016} discusses cool things. 
Some have commented that he's the best \autocite[40]{Smith2018}. 
But later in his work, Jones really goes off the rails \autocite[100]{Jones2016}. 
And by the end of the book, he's talking complete nonsense \autocite[500]{Jones2016}

\end{document}
```

In TeX Live 2020, everything works as expected:
[image: Image of MWE as compiled with TeX Live 2020 on Overleaf]

However, this is what comes out when compiling with TeX Live 2021:

[image: Image of MWE as compiled with TeX Live 2021 on Overleaf]

The standard first-mention `\autocite` command works fine with a postnote, but `\textcite` renders as `Jones (2016: ), 9`, and `\autocite` commands with a postnote that immediately follow a citation of the same work print the postnote delimiter before the page numbers in the parenthetical, instead of printing the page number in parentheses without the delimiter. Note that everything looks as expected with `\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\addspace}` commented out, regardless of which version of TeX Live I compile with:

[image: Image of output with the renewcommand line commented out. Everything looks as expected.]

I don't mind compiling with the 2020 edition of TeX Live, but is there a new "right way" of declaring a global `\postnotedelim` for biblatex-chicago on newer distributions of TeX Live and/or `biblatex-chicago`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual definition of `\postnotedelim` for `authordate` in a current version of `biblatex-chicago` is a bit more complex than the simple `\DeclareDelimFormat{postnotedelim}{\addcomma\space}` in core `biblatex`. `chicago-dates-common.cbx` has

```
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{% Cf. N&B style
  \ifboolexpr{%
    test {\ifciteibid}%
    and
    (
    test {\ifentrytype{jurisdiction}}%
    or
    test {\ifentrytype{legal}}%
    or
    test {\ifentrytype{legislation}}%
    )
  }%
  {\addspace}%
  {\iftoggle{cms@inlineibid}%
    {\togglefalse{cms@inlineibid}%
      \iffieldundef{prenote}% Bug fix
      {}%
      {\setunit{\cms@testspace}}}%
    {\iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{classical}% For Notes+Bib, too?
      {\DeclareNumChars*{abcdeABCDE:}%
        \iffieldpages{postnote}%
        {\setunit{\cms@testspace}}%
        {\newcunit}}%
      {\newcunit}\DeclareNumChars{.}}}}
```

where `\newcunit` is essentially `\setunit{\addcomma\space}`. So if we want colons, we need to replace the `\newcunit` by `\setunit{\addcolon\space}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[authordate]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{% Cf. N&B style
  \ifboolexpr{%
    test {\ifciteibid}%
    and
    (
    test {\ifentrytype{jurisdiction}}%
    or
    test {\ifentrytype{legal}}%
    or
    test {\ifentrytype{legislation}}%
    )
  }%
  {\addspace}%
  {\iftoggle{cms@inlineibid}%
    {\togglefalse{cms@inlineibid}%
      \iffieldundef{prenote}% Bug fix
      {}%
      {\setunit{\cms@testspace}}}%
    {\iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{classical}% For Notes+Bib, too?
      {\DeclareNumChars*{abcdeABCDE:}%
        \iffieldpages{postnote}%
        {\setunit{\cms@testspace}}%
        {\setunit{\addcolon\space}}}%
      {\setunit{\addcolon\space}}\DeclareNumChars{.}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\textcite[9]{sigfridsson} discusses cool things. 
Some have commented that he's the best \autocite[40]{worman}. 
But later in his work, Jones really goes off the rails \autocite[100]{sigfridsson}. 
And by the end of the book, he's talking complete nonsense \autocite[500]{sigfridsson}

\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson and Ryde (1998: 9) discusses cool things. Some have commented that he’s the best (Worman 2002: 40). But later in his work, Jones really goes off the rails (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998: 100). And by the end of the book, he’s talking complete nonsense (500)]

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing me in the right direction. This clears up a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the `chicago-dates-common.cbx` file that [moewe's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/640153/179271) mentions and the `\newcunit` command in particular, it appears that the text component of `\newcunit` is defined by `\newcunitpunct`:

```
\protected\def\blx@newcunit{%
  \iftoggle{blx@keepunit}%
  {}%
  {\global\let\blx@unitpunct\newcunitpunct
    \global\toggletrue{blx@unit}}}%

\appto\blx@blxinit{%
  \let\newcunit\blx@newcunit}%

\newcommand*{\newcunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
```

Adding `\renewcommand*{\newcunitpunct}{\addcolon\space}` to my preamble did exactly what I wanted.

Thanks again to moewe for pointing me to the appropriate file and the appropriate variable for me to get where I wanted to be.

**Update**: The above solution has unintended consequences (as @moewe correctly suggested it would), so my ultimate solution was basically to implement @moewe's answer with `regexpatch` just so it takes up fewer lines (though it probably introduces unnecessary complexity). I've put it here just for completeness's sake, but @moewe's answer seems to be the right way to do it.

```
\usepackage{regexpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd*{\postnotedelim}{\newcunit }{\setunit{\addcolon \addspace} }{}{}
\makeatother
```

(Note that because there are two instances of `\newcunit` in the command, the starred version of `\xpatchcmd` replaces both occurrences of `\newcunit`.)

I'll mark @moewe's answer as correct, since it doesn't rely on any other packages, but just an explicit redefinition.

Comment: Note that `\newcunit` is used in many places in `biblatex-chicago` (especially in the bibliography style, the `authordate` cite style doesn't use it that often), so making it produce colons may have unintended side effects.

Comment: @moewe You're right. It definitely changes some commas to colons in the bibliography itself. I was hoping for an easy, memorable solution, but yours seems to do the trick and avoid any incorrect redefining of variables.